# how to download tables generated on shiny app without html tags?

Tags: r, list, shiny

I have a shiny app where the outputs are some tables generated with tableby() and kbl(). I finally found the way to download those tables as sheets on an excel file, but then i wanted to remove the html tags that were still witten there. I think aplying a function to a list for that purpose is messing with the column names on the .xlsx, which now look weird. I tried using `unname()` to fix it, but it dind't change anything. Is there a way to fix this, or another wey to go around downloading "clean" versions of the tables? Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(arsenal)
library(kableExtra)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("(in true app, user uploads the data)"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      downloadButton(
        outputId = "downloadTable",
        label = "Descargar tabla"
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel(
          "Tabla 1",
          htmlOutput("table")
        ),
        tabPanel(
          "Tabla 2",
          htmlOutput("table2")
      )
    )
  )
)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  ID <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19)
  Provincia <- c("Santa Fe", "Santa Fe", "Cordoba", "Santa Fe", "Santa Fe", "Cordoba", "Cordoba", "Santa Fe", "Cordoba", "Cordoba", "Santa Fe", "Santa Fe", "Santa Fe", "Santa Fe", "Santa Fe", "Cordoba", "Cordoba", "Cordoba", "Santa Fe")
  Ciudad <- c("Carlos Paz", "Esperanza", "Rafaela", "Carlos Paz", "Carlos Paz", "Rafaela", "Villa General", "Belgrano", "Villa General Belgrano", "Rafaela", "Esperanza", "Rafaela", "Esperanza", "Esperanza", "Villa General", "Belgrano", "Carlos Paz", "Carlos Paz", "Esperanza")
  Valor1 <- rpois(n = 19, lambda = 10)
  Valor2 <- runif(n = 19, min = 1, max = 10)
  Color <- c("Rojo", "Azul", "Rojo", "Azul", "Rojo", "Azul", "Rojo", "Azul", "Rojo", "Azul", "Rojo", "Azul", "Rojo", "Azul", "Rojo", "Azul", "Rojo", "Azul", "Rojo")
  df <- data.frame(ID, Provincia, Ciudad, Valor1, Valor2, Color)
  
  
  base <- reactive({
    df
  })

  controles <- reactive({
    tableby.control(
      test = T,
      total = T,
      numeric.test = "anova", cat.test = "chisq",
      numeric.stats = c("meanCI"),
      cat.stats = c("countpct"),
      stats.labels = list(
        meanCI = "Media (95%CI)",
        countpct = "n (%)"
      )
    )
  })
  
  tabla1 <- reactive({
    x <- base()
    
    my_controls <- controles()
    
    tab1 <- tableby(Color ~ Valor1+Valor2,
                    data=x,
                    control=my_controls)
    
    as.data.frame(summary(tab1,digits=1, text = "html"))
    
  })
  
  output$table <- function(){
    
    kable(tabla1(),align = "lccccc", escape = FALSE)%>%
      kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover","condensed","responsive"), full_width = TRUE)
    }
  
  tabla2 <- reactive({
    
    x <- base()
    
    my_controls <- controles()
    
    tab2 <- tableby(Provincia ~ Valor1+Valor2,
                    data=x,
                    control=my_controls)
    as.data.frame(summary(tab2,digits=1, text = "html"))
  })
  
  output$table2 <- function(){
    
    kable(tabla2(),align = "lccccc", escape = FALSE)%>%
      kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover","condensed","responsive"), full_width = TRUE)
  }

  data_list <- reactive({
    lista <- list(
      tabla1(),
      tabla2()
    )
    
    lapply(rapply(lista, function(x)
      gsub("<strong>|</strong>|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;", "", x), how = "list"),
      as.data.frame)
  })
  
  output$downloadTable <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {"prueba1.xlsx"},
    content = function(file) {write_xlsx(data_list(), path = file)}
  )
}
```

Comment: Not sure to understand. Does it help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32400916/1100107 ?

Comment: I don't think so, because i don't have proper html tables; i have dataframes that retained some strings wich i think are html tags: <strong>,</strong> ,&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp...  so, what i need it basically to remove those partial strings from the cells, or to replace them with an empty space so that the dataframes are more easily read when donwnloaded to the xlsx

Comment: Ah ok. But what's the problem with your `gsub` method?

Comment: Well, the gsub actually works fine in doing what it is supposed to do! But when i try to apply it to the whole list, i end up some weird column names on the dataframes on the list when they are downloaded. For example, "Azul (N=9)" turns into "Azul..N.9.". Also the first cell, which should be empty, now is "c..Valor1....Media..95.CI.....Valor2....Media..95.CI...". This is a minimal example, but in reality there are more tables, and that is why i was hoping to apply gsub to all the tables at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `str_remove_all` to get rid of the undesired HTML. Because we have a list and the column we want to edit doesn't have any names it got a little bit convoluted at the end.

Let's change `data_list` reactive to:

```
data_list <- reactive({
    lista <- list(
      tabla1(),
      tabla2()
    )

    map(lista, ~ {
      .x[[1]] %>%
        str_remove_all("<strong>|</strong>") %>%
        str_remove_all("&nbsp;") %>%
        cbind(.x[, -1]) %>%
        set_names(c("", names(.x)[-1]))
    })
  })
```

A simpler manual approach:

```
 data_list <- reactive({
    lista <- list(
      tabla1(),
      tabla2()
    )

    lista[[1]][[1]] <- lista[[1]][[1]] %>%
      str_remove_all("<strong>|</strong>") %>%
      str_remove_all("&nbsp;")
    lista[[2]][[1]] <- lista[[2]][[1]] %>%
      str_remove_all("<strong>|</strong>") %>%
      str_remove_all("&nbsp;")

    lista
  })
```

APP:

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(arsenal)
library(kableExtra)
library(writexl)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("(in true app, user uploads the data)"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      downloadButton(
        outputId = "downloadTable",
        label = "Descargar tabla"
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel(
          "Tabla 1",
          htmlOutput("table")
        ),
        tabPanel(
          "Tabla 2",
          htmlOutput("table2")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ID <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19)
  Provincia <- c("Santa Fe", "Santa Fe", "Cordoba", "Santa Fe", "Santa Fe", "Cordoba", "Cordoba", "Santa Fe", "Cordoba", "Cordoba", "Santa Fe", "Santa Fe", "Santa Fe", "Santa Fe", "Santa Fe", "Cordoba", "Cordoba", "Cordoba", "Santa Fe")
  Ciudad <- c("Carlos Paz", "Esperanza", "Rafaela", "Carlos Paz", "Carlos Paz", "Rafaela", "Villa General", "Belgrano", "Villa General Belgrano", "Rafaela", "Esperanza", "Rafaela", "Esperanza", "Esperanza", "Villa General", "Belgrano", "Carlos Paz", "Carlos Paz", "Esperanza")
  Valor1 <- rpois(n = 19, lambda = 10)
  Valor2 <- runif(n = 19, min = 1, max = 10)
  Color <- c("Rojo", "Azul", "Rojo", "Azul", "Rojo", "Azul", "Rojo", "Azul", "Rojo", "Azul", "Rojo", "Azul", "Rojo", "Azul", "Rojo", "Azul", "Rojo", "Azul", "Rojo")
  df <- data.frame(ID, Provincia, Ciudad, Valor1, Valor2, Color)


  base <- reactive({
    df
  })

  controles <- reactive({
    tableby.control(
      test = T,
      total = T,
      numeric.test = "anova", cat.test = "chisq",
      numeric.stats = c("meanCI"),
      cat.stats = c("countpct"),
      stats.labels = list(
        meanCI = "Media (95%CI)",
        countpct = "n (%)"
      )
    )
  })

  tabla1 <- reactive({
    x <- base()

    my_controls <- controles()

    tab1 <- tableby(Color ~ Valor1 + Valor2,
      data = x,
      control = my_controls
    )

    as.data.frame(summary(tab1, digits = 1, text = "html"))
  })

  output$table <- function() {
    kable(tabla1(), align = "lccccc", escape = FALSE) %>%
      kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed", "responsive"), full_width = TRUE)
  }

  tabla2 <- reactive({
    x <- base()

    my_controls <- controles()

    tab2 <- tableby(Provincia ~ Valor1 + Valor2,
      data = x,
      control = my_controls
    )
    as.data.frame(summary(tab2, digits = 1, text = "html"))
  })

  output$table2 <- function() {
    kable(tabla2(), align = "lccccc", escape = FALSE) %>%
      kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed", "responsive"), full_width = TRUE)
  }

  data_list <- reactive({
    lista <- list(
      tabla1(),
      tabla2()
    )

    map(lista, ~ {
      .x[[1]] %>%
        str_remove_all("<strong>|</strong>") %>%
        str_remove_all("&nbsp;") %>%
        cbind(.x[, -1]) %>%
        set_names(c("", names(.x)[-1]))
    })
  })

  output$downloadTable <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      "prueba1.xlsx"
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write_xlsx(data_list(), path = file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand the simpler manual approach, could you maybe walk me through the other one?

Comment: @Natalias The map function is the tidyverse analog of base *apply functions. `~ { }` is shorthand for writing an anonymous function, in new versions of R is equivalent to `\(.x){}` or just `function(.x){}`. `.x[[1]]` selects the first element (in this case is a vector). `cbind` is to combine the new vector with the part of the strings removed with the old dataframe minus the modified column. Finally, set_names is used to add an empty name in the new column we just edited, here i'm combining and empty string with the previous names present in the dataframe minus the first one.